# Determine the potential of a field with a parameter

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Determine for which parameter value $k$ exists a $U$ potential for:
$$F\left(x,y,z\right)=\left(y^2-kyz,\:2xy+xz+k^2z^2,2yz-kxy\right)$$
Determine $U:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that $U(0,0,0) = 0$

**MY TRY:**
$$\color{red}{U} = \int (y^2-kyz)dx=\left(y^2-kyz\right)x+g(y,z)$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left(U\right) = x\left(2y-zk\right) + g_y(y,z) = 2xy+xz+k^2z^2$$
$$\rightarrow g_y(y,z)=xz+kxz+k^2z^2$$
$$\rightarrow g(y,z)=\left(xz+z^2k^2+xzk\right)y + h(z)$$
So now $$\color{red}{U} = \left(y^2-kyz\right)x + \left(xz+z^2k^2+xzk\right)y + h(z)$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\left(U\right) = yx+2k^2yz+h'(z) = 2yz-kxy$$
$$\rightarrow h'\left(z\right)=2yz-kxy-yx+2k^2yz$$
$$\rightarrow h(z) = -yxz+yz^2-kyxz+k^2yz^2+C$$
Finally:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\color{red}{U} & = \left(y^2-kyz\right)x + \left(xz+z^2k^2+xzk\right)y -yxz+yz^2-kyxz+k^2yz^2+C \\
& = y^2x-kyzx+2k^2yz^2+yz^2+C
\end{aligned}
$$

Is my process correct? I conclude that the potential exists for every $k$ value?(I didn't understand what to do with the parameter $k$).
What about the $U(0,0,0) = 0$?

Comment: $F:\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$ is well defined over all $\mathbb R^3$ forall $k$. Then it will be "grad"-exact if it's "rot"-closed. If it's grad-exact then your get $U$ from integrating (doesn't depend on path taken anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Finally:
>   $$\begin{aligned}
> U = y^2x-kyzx+2k^2yz^2+yz^2+C
> \end{aligned}$$

If you compute the gradient of $U$, you'll find that this isn't equal to the initially given $F$, at least not for all $k$.

There's an easy way to check whether a vector field $F$ is conservative, in which case there exists a potential function $U$ such that $\nabla U = F$; namely $F = (F_1,F_2,F_3)$ is conservative if and only if:
$$\color{red}{\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}} \quad \mbox{and} \quad
\color{green}{\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x}} \quad \mbox{and}
\quad\color{blue}{\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial F_3}{\partial y}}$$
You can easily verify that the green condition is always satisfied, but the red and blue conditions only hold for $k=-1$. Plug this into $F$ and proceed as you did to determine a potential function $U$. Use the condition $U(0,0,0)=0$ to find the extra constant of integration that will pop up.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ok thanks i get: $U\:=\:xy^2+xyz+yz^2+C$, now how can i use $U(0,0,0)=0$ to find the constant od integration?

Comment: @Amarildo Looks good! Now substitute $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ and find $C$ such that $U(0,0,0) = 0$; clearly $C=0$.